# Flutter SetState is not refreshing UI

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building multiple form pages in one class, I create 4 widgets each widgets is represent a page with text fields or cards or radio buttons.
and I create a method to switch between pages when. I press next.
This works as expected ^^

My issue UI inside first page is not refreshed unless I press ctrl + S,,
inside the first page of the form, I have created custom radio buttons they're simply cards.

and when tap on any card, there's set state method, to highlight the selected card by changing its style..

This works perfectly! at the beginning when I call the first page 1 directly as a child inside the scaffold..

However, after I  created the method to switch between pages.. The UI in page 1 does not refresh..

I will put a picture..

[Picture of the method to switch pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDBf5.png)

[Picture of pages widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gISR.png)

[picture of scaffold and how I call the widget pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mpmA.png)

[this is a picture of custom radio button which has cards, the card color change if it's selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wsVU.png)

I tried many ways! but it didn't work..
Is what I'm trying to do correct? I'm a beginner in flutter
& I have a project to submit :(
I couldn't find a solution in google,,

Comment: Just a guess - Try putting  `setState(() {});` at the end of your `switchPage()` method, and removing it from the `newNumber == 1` if block?

Comment: @MSpeed I try removing `setState(() {});` from `newNumber == 1` block, but keep it in other blocks.. still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I did ^^
because the issue was just in page 1, so I in the scaffold I added page 1 as it's child directly without Switch page method..

Then inside page1, a button that will navigate to another class,
the second class has exactly the same scaffold and app bar as previous page.. But, in it's child I added `calledWidget` which switch between pages from 2 to 4 in my case ^^

So short words, I put page 1 in a separate page and the rest of the pages in a switch method in separate class

it works, but I hope I don't find any difficulties When saving values & integrating API to post the values

what you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the widgets `StatefulWidget` and call `setState((){})` inside the widget when you tap on the cards.

Comment: Aww, but `StatefulWidget` can be added to a class. The pages I have, are simply methods of type Widget,, that return a container or column which has all the other widgets inside or `setState((){})`

Comment: `statefulWidget` is also a widget that can return other widgets but the only different that you can set the state of the widgets inside it, we don't usually use methods with widgets unless there's conditions we need to check before showing the widget, but in general we use `statefulWidgets` and `StatelessWidgets`.

Comment: I'm glad! If it helped you please consider clicking on the green checkmark to mark it as correct. Have a nice day :)